# Getting attachments from Exchange Managed API using ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, exchange-server, outlook-addin, office-js

I am in the process of building an Outlook Add-In that authenticates to an external API that is also in my possession. For one of my functions, I am sending a list of attachment IDs from the add-in to the API. I can then use these IDs to get the corresponding attachments from Microsoft's Exchange Managed API. The issue is that because I'm using .NET Core, the recommended libraries are lacking the necessary functionality needed to access the attachments.

Here is some code that I am trying to use to access the attachments from the main `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices` library:

```
ServiceResponseCollection<GetAttachmentResponse> getAttachmentsResponse = service.GetAttachments(attachmentInfo.attachmentIds.ToArray(), null, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent));

if (getAttachmentsResponse.OverallResult == ServiceResult.Success)
{
    foreach (var attachmentResponse in getAttachmentsResponse)
    {
        // removed logic for simplicity
    }
}
```

The issue is that the first line of code throws an error unless I append `.Result` on the end of it. This is some flaw in the .NET Core version of the library. When I go with it, the task never leaves the status of `Awaiting Action` or something similar.

Another library that is supposedly adjusted for .NET Core is `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard`.

Here is some code I found that is suppose to work:

```
var getAttachmentsResponse = service.GetAttachments(attachmentInfo.attachmentIds.ToArray(), null, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent));

foreach (var attachmentResponse in getAttachmentsResponse)
{
    // removed logic for simplicity
}
```

With this sample, the object models are different and there is not even an `Overall Result` on the response. Not to mention, the call fails immediately with errors about there being a duplicate key. I may remember reading somewhere that this method only accepts username/password credentials.

Does anyone have any other solutions that could help me receive attachments from Outlook emails from my API? Am I missing something painfully obvious?

Comment: This looks like an async library ... why don’t you await the call so that you don’t get the Task<T> result but a T ... example var getAttachmentResponse = await service.GetAttachment (....);

Comment: When adding async in front and making the function async (which it requires), I get an error saying 'ServiceResponseCollection<GetAttachmentResponse>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'ServiceResponseCollection<GetAttachmentResponse>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Outlook REST Endpoint for messages and calendar to retrive attachments ,which will return all attachments as array elements with data in  JSON Format

```
var currentAttachments ;
function getAttachments()

    {

       var options ={
           isRest: true,
           asyncContext: { message: 'Hello World!' }
           };

        Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(options, getAttachment);


        function getAttachment(asyncResult)

          {
            var token = asyncResult.value;

            var getAttachmentsUrl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl +
            '/v2.0/me/messages/' + Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId, Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0) + '/attachments';



            $.ajax({
            url: getAttachmentsUrl,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'get',
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }
            }).done(function (item) {

            currentAttachments = item;

            }).fail(function (error) {

            console.log(error);

             });




        }


    }

 // Then we can use Foreach Loop to iterate through these attachments



var outputStringFromRest = "";
                        for (i = 0; i < currentAttachments.value.length; i++) {
                            var _att = currentAttachments.value[i];
                            outputStringFromRest += "<BR>" + i + ". Name: ";
                            outputStringFromRest += _att.Name;
                            outputStringFromRest += "<BR>ID: " + _att.Id;
                            outputStringFromRest += "<BR>contentType: " + _att.ContentType;
                            outputStringFromRest += "<BR>size: " + _att.Size;
                            outputStringFromRest += "<BR>attachmentType: " + "file";
                            outputStringFromRest += "<BR>isInline: " + _att.IsInline;
                        }
```

Comment: I am able to get the attachments from the Rest API from your example. However, what am I suppose to do with this information from here? Can I send this information to the API and somehow use the 'ContentBytes' to actually see or create the attachment in our blob storage?

Comment: Yes,u can use 'contentBytes' which is a 'base64' string to extract attachments content ,by converting a 'base64' string back to original document

Comment: Do you happen to know of an example of this? I am essentially trying to upload this raw 'contentBytes' string into blob storage using MemoryStream. However, whenever I save the string to the stream by converting it to a byte array, the attachments seems to be invalid or corrupted.

Comment: There may be corruption of data while you are sending content bytes from client to Service .to overcome this ,instead of making call from Your Add-in ,construct the Url in following format

 `var getAttachmentsUrl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl +
            '/v2.0/me/messages/' + Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId, Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0) + '/attachments';` and pass it your Service along with 1.5 API REST `token` and make API call from your service.

This may avoid corruption of your data.