# Access to the attachment in Outlook web add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I know I can access to the attachments via `Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments`

Also for each of the attachment I get to access to its members like `name`

But can I actually access to its content and send it to a external server to show it? For example I want to send a pdf attachment to a server, and on the server I want to show the content of that pdf file.

Comment: please check this answer ,hope it will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761482/getting-attachments-from-exchange-managed-api-using-asp-net-core/47767936#47767936

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "on the server I want to show"?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur For example, I have my photo as attachment in my message, I want to transfer the actual content of that photo to a third party server under my control, and that server can save the photo in db probably and also send it to the front-end page to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out  that An Outlook Add-in cannot pass the attachments of a selected item directly to the remote service that runs on your server. Instead, the add-in can use the attachments API to send information about the attachments to the remote service. The service can then contact the Exchange server directly to retrieve the attachments.

```
function getAttachmentToken() {
  if (serviceRequest.attachmentToken == "") {
      Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(attachmentTokenCallback);
  }
}

function attachmentTokenCallback(asyncResult, userContext) {
  if (asyncResult.status === "succeeded") {
      // Cache the result from the server.
      serviceRequest.attachmentToken = asyncResult.value;
      serviceRequest.state = 3;
      testAttachments();
  } else {
      showToast("Error", "Could not get callback token: " + asyncResult.error.message);
  }
}

// Initialize a context object for the add-in.
//   Set the fields that are used on the request
//   object to default values.
var serviceRequest = {
    attachmentToken: '',
    ewsUrl         : Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl,
    attachments    : []
    };
```

[Retrieve attachment via EWS managed API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item)