# How to upload outlook attachments to a web service using outlook add-in (Office add-in)?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

I have a Outlook Add-in developed using VSTO,that among other features allows a user to select attachments from an email and then upload it to a website. The uploading is done by calling an web-service that resides on the website. I want to convert the VSTO add-in to a Office add-in for making the add-in available on platforms other than Windows. I was searching how this can be achieved. As per the SO post here, [Access to the attachment in Outlook web add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762073/access-to-the-attachment-in-outlook-web-add-in), Outlook Add-in cannot pass the attachments of a selected item directly to the remote service that runs on your server. Instead, the add-in can use the attachments API to send information about the attachments to the remote service. The service can then contact the Exchange server directly to retrieve the attachments.

My clients do not use an Exchange server. If Outlook Add-in cannot pass the attachments directly, I need to download the attachments to a temporary folder on the user's machine and then upload it to the web service from the outlook add-in. Is this possible ? Is there any other alternative to achieve what I want ?

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the limitations of Javascript, File access is restricted, although it can be done using localStorage (https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/). To understand your situation better, can you tell us what your clients are using if not an exchange server?

Comment: @devanalyst How did you manage to get the attachments? I have to do more or less the same thing as you (Get them from exchange server, upload to another service). We are using Eschange Server 2013, the only way to get them AFAIK is to use `makeEwsrequest` with the `getAttachments` operation, or have I missed a thing ?

Comment: @Lumpenstein, I am still looking for ways since my clients use a POP server.  is there a way to get attachments from POP server ?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, my clients use a POP server.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to download the attachments to a temporary folder on the user's machine and then upload it to the web service from the outlook add-in. Is this possible ?

This is exactly what I do. Get the path to a folder like Roaming with

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) //C#
```

download the attachments, encode them, create a json object and send them to your service.

This is the most convenient solution imo

Comment: I am moving from VSTO to web add-in which is in Javascript, not C#.

Comment: That was just an example. You can do the same exact thing in JavaScript. Just look up how to access temporary folders on windows

Answer (score 0):

As per this link, Office Add-ins are not supported for Outlook using POP or IMAP accounts.
[Requirements for running Office Add ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins)

I am pasting below the relevant text from the article.

[image: POP and IMAP email accounts in Outlook don't support Office Add-ins]

This is unfortunate. This means there is no way to provide customized solutions in Outlook for the following use-cases.

- **Outlook on Mac or IPad with a POP or an IMAP email account.**